# Query de PostgreSQL (SUM)

Tags: php, postgresql

Supongamos que tengo 2 tiendas las cuales tienen X gastos en suministros, X gastos en contratistas y X gastos en compras.. el tema está es que en la tabla de presupuesto_x_orden yo los estoy identificando por ID, es decir. Si mi ID_TIPO es = 1 entonces es un Contratista, si mi ID_TIPO es = 2 entonces es una COMPRA. El problema está en que yo necesito saber esos 3 gastos para cada tienda pero al realizar la consulta me está duplicando las entradas.. les muestro una foto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los datos que debería poseer realmente en la compra diaria de la tienda Nacar es de 9500.. porque actualmente solo tengo 2 registros, uno de 4500 y uno de 5000.. entonces, lo que está haciendo es duplicarse (seguramente por el group by) 4500*2 + 5000*2 = 19000 entonces no sé que es lo que debería hacer para simplemente hacer esa suma completa de los gastos correspondiendo al ID_TIPO

EDIT: Agrego las imágenes de las tablas por ORDEN

ESTA ES LA TABLA DE PRESUPUESTOS X ORDEN
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ESTA ES LA TABLA DE SUMINISTROS_ORDEN
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ESTA ES LA TABLA DE ORDENES
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ESTA ES LA TABLA DE REPORTES
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualización.. lo que he hecho hasta ahora es separar algunas cosas para no alargar tanto los JOINS.. terminé pasando el costo del artículo a la tabla de suministros_orden para calcular la cantidad solicitada multiplicada por el costo.. así obtengo ese valor..

Los resultados ahora deberían ser estos (formatee la bd)

TOTAL: Aparentemente está bien. SUM: Está mal, actualmente tengo en la tabla de presupuesto_x_orden del tipo 2 que el costo es 1000 y la cantidad es 10.. por lo tanto debería dar 10.000, actualmente me está dando 2000 pero es un error.. si hago la multiplicacion bien me dará 20.000 cosa que está mal, debe dar 10.000
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La sintax del código ahora es esta

```
SELECT orden.fecha as fecha_apertura, orden.id_orden as codigo, orden.id_reporte as id_reporte, 
tienda.nombre_tienda as nombre_tienda, tienda.estado as estado, tienda.ciudad as ciudad, orden.id_estatus as orden_estatus, 
sum(case when suministros.id_estatus != 3 then suministros.costo*suministros.cantidad else 0 end) as total, sum(case when presupuesto.id_tipo = 2 then presupuesto.costo else 0 end), sum(case when presupuesto.id_tipo = 1 then presupuesto.costo else 0 end) as costo_contratista, orden.tipo_responsable as tipo_responsable, reporte.cedula_autor as cedula_autor  
FROM orden_trabajo as orden
LEFT JOIN reportes as reporte on reporte.id_reporte = orden.id_reporte
LEFT JOIN tiendas as tienda on tienda.id_tienda = reporte.id_tienda
LEFT JOIN zonas as zona on zona.id_zona = tienda.id_zona
LEFT JOIN regiones as region on region.id_region = zona.id_region
left join suministros_orden as suministros on suministros.id_orden = orden.id_orden
left join presupuesto_x_orden as presupuesto on presupuesto.id_orden = orden.id_orden
group by presupuesto.id_orden, orden.fecha, orden.id_orden, tienda.nombre_tienda, tienda.estado, tienda.ciudad, orden.id_estatus, reporte.cedula_autor, presupuesto.id_tipo
```

Comment: Se duplica por todos esos joins. sin ver todas las tablas y todos los datos imposible decirte que pasa. El group by no duplica registros.

Comment: Por favor, añade las tablas origen (los datos que nos comentas) para revisar cómo los está usando tu consulta.

Comment: He editado el tópic para dejarlo un poco más claro, gracias por la pronta respuestas chicos!

Comment: Yo veo 7 tablas en tu query, y solo mostras 4.. ademas veo que agregas tablas que parecen solo de vista. Creo que tenes que empezar de nuevo. Hace la suma que necesitas primero con solo las tablas que necesitas. Todo el resto (por ejemplo el nombre de la zona) se puede agregar despues. Usar tantos joins tampoco tiene mucho sentido...

Comment: En eso tienes razón @gbianchi en cuanto pueda editaré todo el tópic entero y colocaré las cosas como son

Comment: Ademas cualquier join de esos, puede hacer que se duplique todo.. Para estas cosas yo recomiendo ir agregando las tablas de a una, e ir verificando que los resultados parciales son correctos.

Comment: @gbianchi ¿Como pudiera hacer si necesito CONSULTAR TODAS LAS TIENDAS y A SU VEZ CONSULTAR LOS GASTOS que tiene cada una? Por ejemplo.. si lo hago con left join solo me mostrará aquellas que tengan registros pero si yo quisiera que me muestre todas mis tiendas y si no tiene gastos me aparezca en 0?

Comment: left join muestra todos los datos que estan a la izquierda.. no entiendo que me estas preguntando...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT orden.fecha as fecha_apertura, orden.id_orden as codigo, orden.id_reporte as id_reporte, 
                tienda.nombre_tienda as nombre_tienda, tienda.estado as estado, tienda.ciudad as ciudad, orden.id_estatus as orden_estatus, 
                sum(case when suministros.id_estatus != 3 then suministros.costo*suministros.cantidad else 0 end) as total, 
                sum(case when presupuesto.id_tipo = 1 then presupuesto.costo else 0 end) as costo_contratista, orden.tipo_responsable as tipo_responsable, reporte.cedula_autor as cedula_autor  
                FROM orden_trabajo as orden
                LEFT JOIN reportes as reporte on reporte.id_reporte = orden.id_reporte
                LEFT JOIN tiendas as tienda on tienda.id_tienda = reporte.id_tienda
                LEFT JOIN zonas as zona on zona.id_zona = tienda.id_zona
                LEFT JOIN regiones as region on region.id_region = zona.id_region
                left join suministros_orden as suministros on suministros.id_orden = orden.id_orden
                left join presupuesto_x_orden as presupuesto on presupuesto.id_orden = orden.id_orden
                group by presupuesto.id_orden, orden.fecha, orden.id_orden, tienda.nombre_tienda, tienda.estado, tienda.ciudad, orden.id_estatus, reporte.cedula_autor, presupuesto.id_tipo
```

Esta es la solución.. y en la vista, agarrando el ID de la orden consultada previamente, se hizo el otro calculo, fin de la historia.